# Google Wallet DOM Exception 18

Tags: android-pay

Google Wallet seems to get stuck at the loading screen and doesn't show the form

```
google.load('payments', '1.0', {
             packages: ['sandbox_config'],
             callback: cbk})
```

Callback is

```
goog.payments.inapp.buy({
    jwt: getToken,
    success: function() {
        console.log("success");
    },
    failure: function() {
        console.log("fail");
    }
});
```

Console shows

```
Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18 5F00.cache.js:23
com_google_checkout_inapp_client_gwt_init_init
```

This is on Google Chrome - Version 25.0.1337.0 dev. It works for me on the demo page, but not on my own pages.

**EDIT**:
Installed Google Chrome Canary - Version 25.0.1347.2 canary

Seems to not be an issue, works perfectly in Canary - is this just a Google Chrome dev glitch or has anyone else seen this?

**EDIT 2**:

Now it doesn't work in canary either (1348) I have also tested in Chrome stable, where it works.

Actually it doesn't seem to be related to the browser version, as reinstalling Canary and wiping Application Support data files makes it work again

Is there a way to get support via email from Google somehow? I know it's Google and they don't talk to people, but maybe there is some way?

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your experiences it seems like a Chrome dev glitch.

Sidenote: I'm not sure if testing your app in dev/canary releases is the best way to catch potential bugs.  Are you also testing in IE/FF/Chrome stable?

Comment: Testing in Chrome Stable works but I dont' think it's browser version related now --

This is for a Google Chrome extension so it is not relevant to IE/FF

Comment: So it works in Chrome Stable? Is there a specific feature you're testing out in the Dev channel?

Comment: It works in any version of Chrome as long as I clear my user data